# the jQuery toggle() function is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to hide and show particular `html table row` using `jQuery toggle()` function?

I have a `html` table that contains a `html form` in its second row. I want the form to be shown when a user clicks on `Show detals` link but `jQuery toggle()` function is not working the way it suppose to work. Whenever i click the `Show Details` link, it shows the hidden table row and then at the same time it hides it again. Below is my code.

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.update_form').hide(); //hides the <tr> tag when the document is ready

      $('#details').click(function(){
          $('.update_form').toggle();
      });
});
```

I tried to bind the `toggle()` and `click()` events with my elements but it does not work untill unless i use `$(document).ready()` event.

But when it works, cliking the `Show Details` link shows the hidden element and then hides
it at the same time without even waiting for the second click.

**html**

```
 <div class="static_archive">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td><b>Ref #:148542657 Title of the ad (468x60)</b><br />Active Running..</td>
       <td>Displayed:0<br />Days Left:30</td>
       <td>
         <a id="pause" href="">Pause</a>
         <a id="details" href="">Show Details</a>
         <a id="activate" href="">Activate</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="update_form"> //I want to this tr for hide and show.
         <td colspan="3"  >
            <div >
               <form>
                  <div class="form_controls">                        
                    <label class="field_label">Banner Title:</label>
        <div class="field_input">
                       <input type="text"  name="banner_title" />                     
        </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form_controls">
           <label class="field_label">Banner URL:</label>
           <div class="field_input">
                      <input type="text"  name="banner_url" /> 
           </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form_controls">
          <label class="field_label">Target URL:</label>
          <div class="field_input">                                                                      
                      <input type="text"  name="target_url" />   
          </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form_controls">
           <label class="field_label">Banner Budget:</label>
           <div class="field_input">
                      <input type="text"  name="banner_budget" />  
           </div>
                </div>
                <br />
               <div class="form_bottom">                         
                  <input type="submit" value="Update!" />
               </div>
         </form>                                            
      </div>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td_img" colspan="3">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>public/images/2.jpg" />
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: @XeroElixir not actually.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña sorry, I'm a noob to jQuery, but that's always what it's done for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use [**`preventDefault()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in this case, as it's an anchor:

```
$('#details').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.update_form').toggle();
});
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHNd8/1/)